# Create Dynamic rdlc file for Reportviewer control C#

Tags: dynamic, reportviewer, rdlc

I want to be able to create dynamic, the xml file with report definition files rdlc for reportviewer control in

System.Windows.Form.

To do this I need the complete documentation of xml structure of the rdlc file.

It's somebody can help me?

I found already the fallowing links:

The best link is :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170667(v=sql.105).aspx

but, is for an particular report. I need something more general, but no complicate like :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article which look good enough for what I need.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240083(v=sql.105).aspx